# Re-exporting FormsModule

Tags: angular

When I try to re-export `FormsModule` it seems to not be working. For example, `ngSubmit` refreshes the pages instead of calling the function and from what I found that happens when `FormsModule` is not imported.

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [],
  exports: [CommonModule,ThemeModule,FlexLayoutModule, FormsModule]
})
export class SharedModule { }

@NgModule({
  imports: [SharedModule],
  declarations: [SomeComponent]
})
export class AuthorizationModule { }
```

Is there some sort of exception for `FormsModule` and it has to be directly imported within each module using it? When I directly import it everything works as expected.

All other re-exported modules work as expected.

**Edit:**

```
<form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" fxLayout="column">
    <md-input-container>
        <input mdInput placeholder="Email" type="email" >
    </md-input-container>
    <md-input-container>
        <input mdInput placeholder="Heslo" type="password">
    </md-input-container>
    <button md-raised-button color="primary" fxFlexAlign="end" type="submit">Přihlásit</button>
</form>

@Component({
  templateUrl: './some.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./some.component.scss']
})
export class SomeComponent {
  onSubmit(){
    alert('submitted');
  }
}
```

Comment: What ? please show us the HTML code of your form.

Comment: Can you reproduce in Plunker?

Comment: Added the component template/code. Working on the functioning Plunker now

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Okey I am lost. Basically copied the whole project (or rather all parts such as routing etc) to Plunker and it works. Is there something you could recommend me to do? E.g when working with visual studio when you stumble on odd behavior it sometimes helps to clear shadow cache etc.

Comment: Sorry, I can't help you here. I'm only working with Dart and with TS only in Plunker for answering SO questions, therefore no experience with TS dev tools. Perhaps someone else. At least it's now narrowed down a lot.

Comment: Seems like the issue was indeed with the tool chain as it has occured since couple times,  It always happened when I installed new package/module and went away after a little while.